# How do I add a placeholder to my UITextField? (Using Xcode 12)

Tags: swift, xcode, uitextfield

[EDIT: New Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1RoQJ.png)Currently using XCode 12, and I'm trying to add a placeholder. I followed the Swift QuestionBot documentation but it doesn't work (I'm assuming it's because my XCode is much newer). Anyway, appreciate all the help!

EDIT: I added an image of a new error I got.

EDIT 2: Added MyQuestionAnswerer() struct! It's on a different view controller (obvious).

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var responseLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var askButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var questionField: UITextField!
    
    let questionAnswerer = MyQuestionAnswerer()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        questionField.becomeFirstResponder()
    }

    func respondToQuestion(_ question: String) {
        let answer = questionAnswerer.responseTo(question: question)

        displayAnswerTextOnScreen(answer)
        questionField.placeholder = "Ask another question..."
        questionField.text = nil
        askButton.isEnabled = false
    }

    @IBAction func askButtonTapped(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        guard questionField.text != nil else {
            return
        }
        questionField.resignFirstResponder()
    }
    
    func displayAnswerTextOnScreen(_ answer: String) {
        responseLabel.text = answer
    }

}

extension ViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        return false
    }

    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        guard let text = textField.text else {
            return
        }
        
        respondToQuestion(text)
    }
    
    @IBAction func editingChanged(_ textField: UITextField) {
        guard let text = textField.text else {
            askButton.isEnabled = false
            return
        }
        
        askButton.isEnabled = !text.isEmpty
    }
}

struct MyQuestionAnswerer {
    
    func responseTo(question: String) -> String {
        let loweredQuestion = question.lowercased()
        
        if loweredQuestion == "What is the current vaccination rate of the Philippines?" {
            return "As of August 8, the vaccination rate of the Philippines is 10%!"
        } else if loweredQuestion.hasPrefix("Where") {
            return "Check the map for nearby vaccination centers."
    }
}
```

Comment: Tap "edit" to edit your question, then you can attach code using the button which looks like this “{}”. This will help us try to solve your problem. Please attach all code relevant to the problem (code to do with UITextField).

Comment: @Demented07 Just did!

Answer (score 1):

The placeholder is not present when the textFiled as it is not set until the `respondToQuestion` method is called. It should probably be set inside of a view controller life cycle method such as `viewDidLoad()`.

Example:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        questionField.placeholder = "Ask another question"
        questionField.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! However, after trying that, I received another error. I'm really sorry but do you mind helping me with it?

Comment: I’ll look at it now

Comment: Can you provide the code for your MyQuestionAnswerer() class please.

Comment: Just did! Thank you.

Comment: @loverofcoding I got one error when I copied your code to test. You forgot to ensure there is a String which is returned if both of the if and else if statements fail. To fix this I added this to the bottom of the if block:
 else {
            return loweredQuestion
        }
I am not sure what you want to be returned if these two conditions fail (I'll leave that up to you to decide.)
If that still doesn't work then please comment back.

Comment: (I am talking about the if block at the bottom inside of your MyQuestionAnswerer struct).

Comment: Hello! I added an "else { return "?" }" at the end - Thanks for catching that! Quick question - you copied all my code, correct? Did you get the bot to work? As in, you submit a question to the text field, you click the button and the top label changes to whatever you asked? That's what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: I copied the Swift QuestionBot code and I really feel like its outdated. Unsure what I'm supposed to change - the text field and button seem to work but the label isn't budging! It doesn't seem to be interactive.

Comment: Sorry what are you meaning when you say 'bot'?

Comment: Oh, that's what it's called - a QuestionBot. Mostly because you ask/type questions into the text field and it's coded so that you get an automatic response. They just call it a bot but it's made using pure Swift on XCode.

Comment: To do this you'll just have to change the label.text to whatever you want the output to be when the askQuestionButton is tapped.

Comment: When I say output I mean the text which is displayed on/in the label.